# Discontinuities in the FFT

Tags: fft, frequency-spectrum, frequency-domain, complex

So I am taking the Fast Fourier Transform of the following function:

$$ x[n] = \displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=0}^{5} A_{i} \cos\left(\frac{\omega_{i}}{\omega_{s}} n + \phi_{i}\right) $$

Where the sampling rate $\omega_{s} = 2 \pi 8000$, the frequencies $\omega$, the phases $\phi$ and the amplitudes $A$ are: 
\begin{align}
\omega &= 2 \pi \{500, 522, 610, 675, 746, 825 \}\\
\phi &= \{0,0,0,0,0,0\}\\
A &= \{1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1\}
\end{align}

The length of the signal is $N = 2048$ samples. No window is applied before taking the FFT.

The resulting FFT spectrum should have only a real component since the imaginary component should be zero. However, when taking the FFT and plotting the spectrum I get the following:

[image: Real Spectrum]
[image: Imaginary Spectrum]

Why is the imaginary part not zero? It seems to be a discontinuity. However, I am not sure why it exists. Why does the imaginary part of the spectrum look like this?

Comment: What do you get if you apply a window?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your parameters aren't correct for producing a whole number of cycles for each component.

For each $i$ the value of $ \frac{\omega_{i}}{\omega_{s}} N $ has to be a multiple of $ 2 \pi $.

Hope this helps.

Ced

---

Followup:

Suppose your signal is

$$ x[n] = A \cos( \alpha n + \phi ) $$

If $ \phi \neq 0 $ there is a possible solution which will give you a strictly real valued DFT bins besides one with a whole number of cycles.  The condition that must be met is: $ \alpha N + 2 \phi $ must be a multiple of $ 2 \pi $.

For a whole number of cycles, your only non-zero bins will be at $ k $ and $ N-k $ where $ k $ is the number of cylces in the frame.  There is no leakage.  The bins will be real valued if $\phi = 0 $ or $\phi = \pi $.

For the alternative above, there will be leakage and it will all be real valued.

Edit:  A simpler way of stating this is that your signal has to be symmetric about the center of your interval.

---

Response to comment:

Sorry, I didn't see your comment until after I posted the followup.

The mathematical answer lies in equations (23) through (25) in my blog article ["DFT Bin Value Formulas for Pure Real Tones"](https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/771.php).

In order to have strictly real valued bin values, the value of $ U $ must be zero.  For whole numbers of cycles, $ V $ is also zero and eq (25) becomes undefined at the relevant bins and you have to use equation (19).  The alternative solution in my followup makes $ U $ zero, but not $ V $.

Comment: Okay I know that, but, so what? Is this the problem? If so, how can we show this mathematically?

Comment: But my leakage is not real valued, it is complex valued. So how does this relate? 

From what I am understanding, you are saying to minimize leakage by selecting a sampling rate or length such that the frequencies fall on a DFT bin. This way, I won't get any of this imaginary garbage out in the FFT?

I am going to take a look at your blog to understand deeper.

Comment: @The Dude, I am wondering why you consider the imaginary part garbage.

Comment: Thank you so much for the link to the blog post. It answered my question 100%. Great article, and many thanks!

Comment: Cedron, only because I didn't want it. Thanks to your blog post, I understand why it is there. Thanks again, it was very informative and well written.

Comment: @The Dude, You can find all my blog articles by clicking on the red "Cedron Dawg" label in the articles or there is a link on my profile page here.  I'm glad my article was helpful to you.  I suspect you will find the first two even more so:  "The Exponential Nature of the Complex Unit Circle" and "DFT Graphical Interpretation: Centroids of Weighted Roots of Unity"

Comment: So, I understand the U & V formula in general, and why it is producing the discontinuities (due to the denominator) however, can this exposition explain why the discontinuities will only be in the imaginary part when the transform is real, then only in the real part when the transform is imaginary, and in both when the transform is complex valued? I think this is an important point to cover.

Comment: @The Dude, I don't quite understand your question.  Feel free to email me at cedron at exede dot net to continue.  U and V are both real valued.  The denominator is also real valued.  Suppose that f is somewhere between k and k+1.  If N is large, the numerator will be roughly the same complex value at k and k+1.  However, the real valued denominator will switch signs, thus making the bin values at k and k+1 nearly opposite direction of each other on the complex plane.  This is something that gets wiped out when you are only looking at magnitudes.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to produce strictly real FFT results (other than numerical rounding/quantization noise in the imaginary component) is to make sure that the wave form is circularly symmetric around time domain sample 0.  For a cosine function starting with a phase of 0, this can be produced by doing an FFT shift (circularly rotating the input vector by N/2 samples).

This will work whether or not the cosine is exactly integer periodic in the FFT aperture, since it produces an purely even function around sample 0, which always produces a strictly real FFT result.

Comment: This is a really practical answer. Thanks for this!